# How to stagger execution of parallel specs?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, end-to-end

The app I am testing has a concurrency limit of ~6 instances. I am running a paralleled test suite with about 9 concurrent sessions. Is there a reliable way to stagger the execution to ensure I don't hit the concurrency limit?

One solution I have been trying to work out is to put a randomized timeouts in the OnPrepare() but that is not as reliable as I would like.

Comment: Are you using shards in your protractor conf to achieve these 9 concurrent sessions? You can limit it to 6 by adding `capabilities: { shardTestFiles: true, maxInstances: 6}` to your conf file.

Comment: Yes I am. Thanks but that is not something I am looking for